# Default way to manage static files in Django

Tags: python, django, web-applications, django-staticfiles

Im trying to get rid of `404` with Django local server.
My page includes this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/myjscript.js"></script>
```

Actual file lies in `C:/Users/PyCharmProjects/MyProject/MyApp/static/js/myjscript.js`
Django docs [says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#basic-usage):

> Put your static files somewhere that staticfiles will find them.
>
> *By default, this means within static/ subdirectories of apps* in your
>   INSTALLED_APPS.

I believe my setup fit to defaults, but I still getting `404`, why so?
Kindly help!

### UPDATE

Solved this with simply using [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/#with-a-template-tag) approach:

```
{% load static %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/myjscript.js' %}"></script>
```

In the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/#with-a-template-tag) they saying about configuring `STATICFILES_STORAGE`, but I didnt even touch it, and get `200` for these files now.

This place of Django - static files - seems pretty dark and unclear for me. I cant understand purpose of such many sophisticated solutions for such simple task.

If somebody will point to good not-obscure manual for all this, I will highly appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/myjscript.js">
```

[This page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) is where I got my information from.

In case that site is down, they give an example:

```
 <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/hi.jpg" alt="Hi!" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it goes without saying, make sure that `STATIC_URL` is set to something intelligent in your `settings.py`.  I don't know what this gets set to by default in a Windows deployment.

Comment: It was `/static/` by default